# Why we use "this" in Extension Methods?

Tags: c#

I want to ask why we use "this" keyword before the parameter in an extension method (C# Language)...........
like this function :

```
    public static int ToInt(this string number)
    {
        return Int32.Parse(number);
    }
```

I know that we have to use it but I don't know why.

Comment: Scott Hanselman has a good article that explains that importance of the "this" keyword. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowDoExtensionMethodsWorkAndWhyWasANewCLRNotRequired.aspx

Comment: I would have personally preferred an Attribute. Something like [Extends(typeof(foo)] and then had an implicit variable called value, similar to properties. It would have been more expressive and not required a reuse of an existing keyword. Just my personal opinion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because that's the way you tell the compiler that it's an extension method in the first place. Otherwise it's just a normal static method. I guess they chose `this` so they didn't have to come up with a new keyword and potentially break old code.

Comment: And so you didn't have to tag the method with the ExtensionAttribute like you do in VB.Net.

Comment: C# has more delicious syntactic sugar, and that's why I love it.

Comment: Why not simply accept all static methods with at least one parameter as an extension method?

Comment: @ThomasEyde That makes it more likely to have name collisions, and also would probably cause a lot of undesirable methods to show up in code completion. This gives the library author a choice.

Answer (score 6):

For info, the significance of `this` as a contextual-keyword here is largely that it avoids introducing a *new* keyword. Whenever you introduce a new keyword you risk breaking code that would have used it as a variable / type name. `this` has a few useful features:

- it is *close enough* to indicating that this relates to an instance method
- it is an existing keyword...
- ...that would have been illegal when used in that location

This means that no **existing** code will be broken.

Beyond the choice of `this` as the keyword, it is just a convenient syntax for the compiler, and more convenient than adding `[Extension]` manually. Without either, it would just be a static method, without any special behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It simply marks it as an extension method, this is the format they chose to go with to define the method as an extension method, as opposed to a plain static method (which is how it's called internally anyway).  This is **only for the compiler** (and intellisense), under the covers your code compiles the same as if you were just calling the static method directly.

This definition for a method:

```
public static int ToInt(string number) //non extension
```

Needed to be distinguishable from this:

```
public static int ToInt(this string number) //extension
```

Otherwise you'd have intellisense containing every static method in a static class in included namespaces, very undesirable.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly because it is how the [C# spec](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/8/8/388e7205-bc10-4226-b2a8-75351c669b09/CSharp%20Language%20Specification.doc) defines an extension method.  **See Section 10.6.9**

> **10.6.9 Extension methods**
>
> When the first parameter of a method
>   includes the *this* modifier, that
>   method is said to be an extension
>   method. Extension methods can only be
>   declared in non-generic, non-nested
>   static classes. The first parameter of
>   an extension method can have no
>   modifiers other than this, and the
>   parameter type cannot be a pointer
>   type.

Answer (score 0):

In order to identify the method as an extension method. How else would the compiler know?

Answer (score 0):

It's just the syntax that was chosen to indicate an extension method. Here's an interesting view point on the extension method syntax differences between C# and vb.net:
[Extension Method Implementation differences between C# and VB.NET](http://www.rocksthoughts.com/blog/archive/2008/03/11/extension-method-implementation-differences-between-c-and-vb.net.aspx)