# Explanation of Extension Methods in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What are Extension Methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/403539/what-are-extension-methods)
>   [Extension Methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730013/extension-methods)

Could someone explain the concept of extensions methods with examples if possible please

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise modifying the original type

Refer to:

[Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)