# passing this as parameter in static method

Tags: c#, this, parameter-passing

I'm having some trouble with some code in Visual C# for Windows Phone
The trouble is not that it does not work, because it does, but I don't understand how =P
Within a static class, a static method is created, which gives itself as a parameter:

```
public static void MethodONe( this Timeline animation )
{
    //this class does not extend the TimeLine class, and is not connected to it in any                   
    //such way.
    animation.MethodTwo( );
}

public static void MethodTwo( this Timeline animation )
{
    someCode( );
}
```

How is this parameterpassing called, and what does it do, exactly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are Extension Methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/403539/what-are-extension-methods), [Extension Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5730013/extension-methods), [Why we use “this” in Extension Methods?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574311/why-we-use-this-in-extension-methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a so called extention method to the Timeline object. It adds functionallity without modifying the class itself.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

And in your case the animation parameter is the Timeline object (which is calling the function):

```
var timeLine = new Timeline();
timeLine.MethodTwo();
```

So the timeLine object will be passed as the animation parameter into the function.
There's a nice article on wikipedia which explains it futher in detail:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extension_method

Comment: "...the parameter this is the Timeline object..." - that's not really correct. `this` is a _modifier_ in that case, not a _parameter_. The parameter is `animation` :-)