# C# How to create your own data structure methods

Tags: c#

I've been trying to google one interesting fact for me, but can't grab the terminology to fully understand this concept. For example, I create my own container which holds an array of Cars. For this specific array I want to implement "Place" method which inserts a given car in a specific order (place method has logic). And what I don't get is how it gets the job done. Here is the code:

```
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      Car[] result = new Car[entries];
      result.Place(poppedValue);
   }
```

```
    public static class Extension
    {
        public static void Place(this Car[] array, Car car)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
            {
                if (array[i] != null)
                {
                    if (array[i].Year > car.Year)
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    public class Car
    {
        public string Name;
        public int Year;
        public double MPG;

        public Car(string name, int year, double mpg)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Year = year;
            this.MPG = mpg;
        }

        public bool ComplexMaths()
        {
            return (Year * MPG) % 2 == 0;
        }
    }
```

What I don't get is that in "Place" method, first argument is "this Car[] array" and when calling the method "Place" you don't give that argument. C# understands it by using result.Place... It's so confusing. Maybe someone can say what happends under the hood and how this "function" of C# is called. I would like to read about it more. Thank you.

Comment: Extension Methods are under the hood https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why we use "this" in Extension Methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574311/why-we-use-this-in-extension-methods)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extension method is a syntactic sugar that allows functionality to be added to existing classes even if sealed and without inheriting them.

This is also called a [Trait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_(computer_programming)).

In C# we use the keyword `this` for the first parameter to indicate that the static method, that must be in a static class generally called a Helper class, applies to the specified type.

For example:

```
public static class CarArrayHelper
{
    public static void Place(this Car[] array, Car car)
    {
    }
}
```

Indicates that we can apply the `Place` method on all arrays of `Car`.

Hence we can write:

```
var myArray = new Car[10];

myArray.Place(new car());
```

This is exactly the same as:

```
CarArrayHelper.Place(myArray, new car());
```

The `Car` class does not implement `Place`, so we added the functionality without changing the `Car` class or creating a subclass.

Here are some tutorials:

[C# - Extension Method (TutorialsTeacher)](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-extension-method)

[Extension Methods in C# (C-SharpCorner)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/puranindia/extension-methods-in-C-Sharp-3-0/)

[Extension Method in C# (GeeksForGeeks)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/extension-method-in-c-sharp/).